# How to move to particular templates/xxx.html and controller when user start typing word in search field. AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

This is my routeProvider code. and its working fine by clicking on respective link.

```
sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/Login', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/ShowLogin.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        }).
        when('/SignUp', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/SignUp.html',
            controller: 'SignupController'
        }).
        when('/ForgotPassword', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/ForgotPassword.html',
            controller: 'PasswordController'
        }).
        when('/ShoppingCart', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/ShoppingCart.html',
            controller: 'ShoppingCartController'
        }).

        when('/Products/:SCId', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/Products.html',
            controller: 'ProductsController'
        }).


        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/Login'
        });
}]);
```

My questions is can we move to any particular templates/xxx.html and controller if instead click on link, I start typing in text field.
Actually my requirement is as soon as user start typing in search field in HTML page, control should move to

```
templateUrl: 'templates/Products.html',
controller: 'ProductsController'
```

Please provide the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-include to place any particular template & controller in that page.

Use `ng-if` and show/hide the products results based on the search results.

```
<div ng-include src="'templates/Products.html'" ng-if="searchfieldmodel" ></div>
```

Inside that page, add the appropriate controller.

Use appropriate CSS to show/hide other contents of the page.

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried this approach, but it just loading the template not the controller.

Comment: Mention the controller name in your template file or in your ng-include

Comment: I'm trying this way: But it doesnt seems to work. <div ng-include ng-controller="ProductsController" src="'templates/Products.html'" ng-if="SearchText" ></div>

Comment: `<div ng-controller="ProductsController">
<div ng-include src="'templates/Products.html'" ng-if="SearchText" ></div>
</div>` this will work

Comment: setup a jsfiddle, would do it for you

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working perfectly. I was having some other issue, because of that it was not working.

Comment: One more thing, suppose i have 10 ng-route, so i need to put ng-include in every page? There is no clean way to achieve this.

Comment: Nope, you can use ng-swithc-when for that purpose. But mostly you need to use $location.path and navigate to that route.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a $watch on your scope model:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.userKeyed = '';
    $scope.$watch('userKeyed', function(newVal) {
        if (newVal && newVal.length > 0) 
            $location.path = '/products/' + newVal;
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
   <input type="text" ng-model="userKeyed" />
</div>
```